# Scoped CSS using @import in style attribute?

Tags: html, css

[This](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515) W3C draft (from 2002) mentions an intriguing way of having scoped CSS (apparently in HTML 4) using the style attribute and the @import statement in CSS. More precisely, they give the following example (example 4, section 2)

> 4. Importing a style sheet to apply as a scoped style sheet:

```
<div class="navigation">
          style="@import url(navigationstyles.css);">...</div>
```

> This document defines ... and scoped style sheets (the use of >@import which apples the referenced style sheet to the subdocument >consisting of the element and its children with the element as the root, >example 4).

Now, the problem is: it doesn't work (even after removing the obvious syntax error). Using the @import statement in the style attribute has absolutely no effect (in recent versions of Safari and Firefox).

So **my question is**: did the authors of this draft just make a mistake, or is this example correct and I'm just missing something?

Comment: why you have an '>' after your class ending ? it should be  <div class="navigation" style="@import url(navigationstyles.css);">...</div>

Comment: Because I quoted the example verbally, including the 'obvious syntax error' I mentioned.

Comment: They probably removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a newer version of that specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/) (from 2013) which is a Recommendation instead of a Draft. The example you quote has been removed.

The authors didn't make a mistake. They wrote a draft which was later revised.

Comment: Seems so, unfortunately :(Latest version gives the following grammar for values of "style": `declaration-list : S* declaration? [ ';' S* declaration? ]*;` In particular, no @import is allowed :(